# Sending a json string as query parameter via spring web client

Tags: java, json, spring, http, spring-webclient

I am trying to use the code below to send across a json string as a query param using Spring WebClient.

```
var client = WebClient.builder()
         .baseUrl(baseurl)
         .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
         .build()
client.post().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/api/SomeRequest")
                  .queryParam("response", responseJsonStr).build()   
                  ).retrieve().bodyToMono(ReponseObj.class).block()
```

I am seeing a error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variables available to expand questionKey.
```

From the searching I have done, I can tell the issue is around the the Json String I am supplying as a query parameter(It has '{' and '}'). I think this might have to do with URI encoding. But looking at the details around encoding , I am not sure what the best way to approach this is.
NOTE: I can't make changes to the server that is expecting the Json string as a query param(it later decodes the json after extracting the query param).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you know that it's a really bad idea to send a json string as query param and not as post body, so I will not go into it any furhter.

You were right. You have to encode the query parameter on the client side to make it work. You can simply encode the param like this:

```java
.queryParam("response", URLEncoder.encode(responseJsonStr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

Just make sure that you use the same character set as the server side.